# How to change the color of the placeholder text using react-bootstrap-typeahead?

Tags: react-bootstrap-typeahead

Using [react-bootstrap-typeahead](https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead) there is an option to provide placeholder text.

How can I change the color of this text? I can't find the relevant selector to target the placeholder text element on the [demo page](http://ericgio.github.io/react-bootstrap-typeahead/):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/31045763/906814 - it's completely unrelated to react-bootstrap-typeahead, which after all just creates a standard input with a placeholder:

```
input[type="text"]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: red;
}
```